# Concat columns with extra column == column name

Tags: python, reshape, concatenation

I want to concat a dataframe where I place every columns under each other and add an extra column to indicate to which column the value belongs to.

```
current=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[3,4,5,6]})

desired = pd.concat([current['a'], current['b']])
desired
```

so in de desired DF there needs to be added an extra column, like:
extra column
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
the values of the extra column should be placed vertically ofc.

many thanks, hopefully I explained it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you can use the `pd.melt()` function like so:

```
pd.melt(current, var_name='col_name')

  col_name  value
0        a      1
1        a      2
2        a      3
3        a      4
4        b      3
5        b      4
6        b      5
7        b      6
```

Comment: awesome, it works! I want to set ignore_index=False, but then I get the following error: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index' Am I missing something?